# How to get TextView values from a listView Items?

Tags: android

I tried to get answer from different similar questions here but didn't get any answer.
Actually I am trying to get values from multiple textViews of any listview item(s).
Here is the code
    ListView listView = getListView();

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int postion, long id) {               
        String contactId = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.cid)).getText().toString();
        String contactName= ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactName)).getText().toString();
        String contactNo= ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactNo)).getText().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), editContactActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(TAG_ID, contactId );
        i.putExtra(TAG_NAME, contactName);
        i.putExtra(TAG_CONTACT_NO, contactNo);
        startActivityForResult(i, 100);     
    }   
});
```

What result i am getting, I am getting textviews value of first item(Position) in listview, either i am clicking any item but i am getting textviews value of first item(Position) in listview,
Here is the code how i am getting values on other activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_contact);

    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveContact);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteContact);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    cId = i.getStringExtra(TAG_CONTACT_ID);
    cNameTxt = i.getStringExtra(TAG_CONTACT_NAME);
    cNumberTxt = i.getStringExtra(TAG_CONTACT_NUMBER);

    //Log.d("Value of contact name", cNameTxt);
    //Log.d("Value of contact name", cNumberTxt);


    TextView contactIdTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cid);
    cName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCName);
    cNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCNumber);


    cName.setText(cId);
    cNumber.setText(cNumberTxt);

}
```

I will be very thankful if anyone will help in detail
Thanks
Regard
Akmal Rasool

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> I am getting textviews value of first item(Position) in listview

Every time you use `findViewById()` tell it to look in this row *only*:

```
(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cid)
//Add this ^^^^^
```

---

All together:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int postion, long id) {
    String contactId = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cid)).getText().toString();
    //             Again use view  ^^^^^
    // Repeat this for contactName and contactNo
```

Answer (score 0):

to obtain the textView value, try this.

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.correoEncuestador);
            String message= text.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), message,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
View parentView = (View) view.getParent();
    textview1 = ((TextView) parentView
            .findViewById(R.id.textview1)).getText().toString();

    textview2 = ((TextView) parentView
            .findViewById(R.id.textview2)).getText().toString();

    textview3 = ((TextView) parentView
            .findViewById(R.id.textview3)).getText().toString();
```